# how to add shortcut of drive to asp.net project?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have mapped drive in my server which contains some mp3 files and other images, now I have jQuery plugin (jPlayer) to play mp3 files, the problem these mo3 files that I need are located in Z: drive, which is not part of asp.net project, the player of course require the path of mp3 file to play it, for example, http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-03-Lentement.mp3,

I was thinking about solution, it comes up to my mind to create shortcut of z: drive in asp.net project, so it would looks like any other folder in asp.net project, but that didn't work with me,

any help, or idea please?

Answer (score 1):

Your mp3 files need to be accessible on a url.  To do this, you can map the folder on Z where they are as a Virtual Directory in IIS.  *Note that this will make them public to anyone that knows where they are.*

Comment: thanks, but virual directory is not working with me for network drives ! any help please?

Answer (score 1):

Symlinks are what you need to do.

You would place an symlink that is a folder location in your project to your z: drive. The "mklink /D" makes a link while the first parameter is the source and second is the alias.

```
mklink /D Z:\ C:\projects\my-project\z-files
```

See the following reference;

http://waxideal.com/blog/2010/03/29/using-windows-7-symlinks/

Comment: thanks, when I am using mklink /D Z:\ C:\projects\my-project\z-files it gives me error: The system cannot find the path specified. here is my try --->  
mklink /D Z:\ C:\Users\khaled\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\LAMS_Admin\audio and by the way I make sure the path z: and the project path is correct because I copy paste them in windows explorer !

Comment: I would refer to here -> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194%28v=ws.10%29.aspx for more information on mklink as it may help you to try other switches such as "/j" for junction instead. Also try playing with the "z:" or try a sub directory within "z:\files"